Performance Counter Report w/ Powershell and Cooked Values
I'm trying to capture available size, remaining size, and a number of logical disk counters for my D:\ drive. however the following are the results I get
    "Used Space" and "Free Space" appear to be bloated and are incorrect
    All remaining columns have "System.Object[]" as its output

"Date","Used Space","Free Space","% Disk Read Time","% Disk Time","% Disk Write Time","% Free Space","Avg. Disk sec/Read","Avg. Disk sec/Write","Disk Reads/sec","Disk Writes/sec","Free Megabytes"
"7/17/2024 6:12:03 PM","2605547520","126240321536",,,,,,,,,

I not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've heard of cooked values but not sure where I would use this parameter here.
# Capture disk space information
$diskInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='D:'" | Select-Object Size, FreeSpace

# Capture performance monitor counters
$perfCounters = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk | Select-Object PercentDiskReadTime, PercentDiskTime, PercentDiskWriteTime, PercentFreeSpace, AvgDisksecPerRead, AvgDisksecPerWrite, DiskReadsPersec, DiskWritesPersec, FreeMegabytes, Timestamp

# Create a custom object with the required properties
$finalData = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Used Space" = $diskInfo.Size - $diskInfo.FreeSpace
    "Free Space" = $diskInfo.FreeSpace
    "% Disk Read Time" = $perfCounters.PercentDiskReadTime
    "% Disk Time" = $perfCounters.PercentDiskTime
    "% Disk Write Time" = $perfCounters.PercentDiskWriteTime
    "% Free Space" = $perfCounters.PercentFreeSpace
    "Avg. Disk sec/Read" = $perfCounters.AvgDisksecPerRead
    "Avg. Disk sec/Write" = $perfCounters.AvgDisksecPerWrite
    "Disk Reads/sec" = $perfCounters.DiskReadsPersec
    "Disk Writes/sec" = $perfCounters.DiskWritesPersec
    "Free Megabytes" = $perfCounters.FreeMegabytes
    "DateTime" = $perfCounters.Timestamp
}

# Export the data to a CSV file
$finalData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\myburger.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Thanks in advance

Check to see if the disk is fragmented?

you specify a filter for just D: in the first call, do the same for the second... $perfCounters = Get-WmiObject -filter "Name='D:'" win32_PerfFormatted...

Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk

Will always return multiple values, you can see that when just running the cmdlet in itself. You will have to select one of those values:
(Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk)[0]

It works fine for me then:
Used Space          : 25482530816
Free Space          : 28068241408
% Disk Read Time    : 0
% Disk Time         : 0
% Disk Write Time   : 0
% Free Space        : 47
Avg. Disk sec/Read  : 0
Avg. Disk sec/Write : 0
Disk Reads/sec      : 0
Disk Writes/sec     : 0
Free Megabytes      : 62752
DateTime            : 

Concerning the error for win32_logicaldisk, the error is not to find in the script.

While the logical disk [0] array selection works on my laptop. It still returned "System.Object[0]" errors when attempted on a VM or VDI. I think it may have something to do with the fact that C:, D:, and E: share the same physical cluster volume. So I took this route instead which seems to compensate for the setup.
cls

# Get drive information for the D:\ drive
$DriveInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='D:'" | Select-Object Size, FreeSpace

# Calculate used space

$totalspace = [math]::round($DriveInfo.Size / 1GB, 2)
$freespace = [math]::round($DriveInfo.Freespace / 1GB, 2)

# Get the current date and time

$Counters = @(
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\processor(_total)\% processor time',
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\memory\% committed bytes in use',
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\memory\cache faults/sec',

    # Logical Disk Data

    '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% disk read time',
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% disk time',
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% disk write time'
    '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% free space',
    # '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% Idle time',
    # '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\disk reads/sec',
    # '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\disk writes/sec',
    # '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\% Idle time',
    # '\\elecopspiasprd1\physicaldisk(_total)\free megabytes'

)
Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -MaxSamples 1 | ForEach {
    $_.CounterSamples | ForEach {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            TimeStamp = $_.TimeStamp
            Path = $_.Path
            Value = $_.CookedValue
            UsedSpace = $totalspace
            FreeSpace = $freespace
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "D:\OSIsoft\ProcessMonitor\burgertimereports.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

The code works fine. Only challenge is in identifying the correct parameters for powershell to call (e.g. % Idle Time throws an error as PowerShell does not recognize it)
